# Rails cannot find model with same name as Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and I have a project with a "Set" model. This is in Rails 2.3.2. Now the problem is that it can't find any methods on that model's class at all. For example: "undefined method `find' for Set:Class" or "undefined method`errors' for #". It seems to be trying to find those methods on the Ruby "Set" class instead my model class.

It might work if I could write the fully-qualified name of my Set model class like Module::Set, but I'm not sure what that would be. (And yes, I really do want my model name Set. Anything else would be awkward in the context of my app).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't name it Set. That way lies madness.

The deal is that defining the class fails because you're trying to redefine 'Set' which is already defined in the global context.

```
class Set < ActiveRecord::Base # You are attempting to define a constant 'Set'
                               # here, but you can't because it already exists
```

You can put your class in a module, and then you won't get the error because you'll be defining Set within a namespace.

```
module Custom
  class Set < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

However, every single time you want to use your Set class, you'll have to refer to it as Custom::Set. A lot of Rails magic won't work because it's expecting class names to be defined in the global context. You'll be monkeypatching plugins and gems left and right.

Far easier to just give it a different name.

```
class CustomSet < ActiveRecord::Base
```

All the magic works, and no monkeypatching required.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to think of another name.

Comment: Sarah is right, and this is a shortcoming of Rails itself that I'd like to see fixed. Unseasoned Rails developers are already way too ActiveRecord-centric in their thinking, resulting in bloated models. In my apps, easily 90% of my code is in the lib directory - fully test-driven, and namespaced to play nicely with others. A class shouldn't get priority in the global namespace simply because there's a db table behind it.