# Rails model fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a data model which has the name 'rack'.  When I generate a model with this name in my Rails project, I get errors when launching the server.

```
load_missing_constant: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
```

I am not using Rack Middleware and I don't see 'rack' as a reserved word in Ruby or Rails.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you're using a recent version of Rails, you actually *are* using Rack middleware, since that's how several Rails components are implemented these days (Rails as a whole is, in fact, a Rack application now).  As such, there's already a constant named Rack, so when you try to create an ActiveRecord model called Rack, there's a collision.  I'm not sure why you get that particular error, though - when I tried it on a toy project, I got this error trying to run the migration:

```
jhyland@john-hylands-macbook: ~/tmp/foo $ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/jhyland/tmp/foo)
rake aborted!
Rack is not a module
```

Regardless, I strongly suspect that this is the underlying cause of your problem.  Would it be possible to change the name of your model?

Comment: Name collisions cause all kinds of strange errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960781/rails-cannot-find-model-with-same-name-as-ruby-class

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your `config/environment.rb` file to remove ActiveRecord?

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  #...

  # Skip frameworks you're not going to use. To use Rails without a database,
  # you must remove the Active Record framework.
  config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]

  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of rails are you running?

As of 2.3, 
[rails runs on Rack](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/3/16/rails-2-3-templates-engines-rack-metal-much-more)